# Combine AWS CLI and CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a new user pool in AWS Cognito. As you might know, CF support is missing for a lot of the features in Cognito, so I´ve resorted to using the CLI for Cognito. But I still want to use CloudFormation for other resources like API Gateway that will need to reference the new user pool.

Is there any way I can create parameters with the CLI that I can use in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have `Parameters` in your template, then you can use the [CloudFormation Deploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html) command to do exactly this.

For example, you can call `aws cloudformation deploy --template-file <file_path> --stack-name <stack_name> --parameter-overrides ParameterKey1=ParameterValue1 ParameterKey2=ParameterValue2 ...` where `<file_path>` is the path to your CloudFormation Template, and `<stack_name>` is the name of your CloudFormation Stack. If this stack doesn't exist yet, Deploy will create it, but if it does exist, Deploy will update it.